# Flutter multi select and delete list

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of items from Firestore in ListViewBuilder. I want to add the multi-select function and perform a function for the selected checkboxes.
I want that when the checkbox is tapped, it should be selected (and multiple of the checkboxed can be selected.), and when the listTile is selected something should happen.

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:hithcride/UTILS/utils.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:text_scroll/text_scroll.dart';

class GeneralNotification extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userCollection;
  final String notificationCollection;
  final String errorString;
  final String noNotificationYetString;
  final String notificationAppBarTitleString;
  final navigateToHomePage;
  const GeneralNotification(
      {super.key,
      required this.userCollection,
      required this.notificationCollection,
      required this.errorString,
      required this.noNotificationYetString,
      required this.notificationAppBarTitleString,
      this.navigateToHomePage});

  @override
  State<GeneralNotification> createState() => _GeneralNotificationState();
}

class _GeneralNotificationState extends State<GeneralNotification> {
  List<int> selectedList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Utils().customAppBarTitleAndNav(context, 100,
          widget.notificationAppBarTitleString, widget.navigateToHomePage),
      body: Container(
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight,
        decoration: Utils().decoration(),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection(widget.userCollection)
              .doc(uid)
              .collection(widget.notificationCollection)
              .orderBy("Time", descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(widget.errorString);
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final info = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  List<bool> isCheckedList =
                      List.filled(snapshot.data!.docs.length, false);
                  var timestamp = info.get("Time") as Timestamp;

                  // var dateFormat = DateFormat("dd.M.yyy  hh:mm");
                  DateTime timeStamppp =
                      DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString());
                  String time =
                      DateFormat("EEE dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm").format(timeStamppp);
                  final selectedUID = info.get("uid");
                  final isRead = info.get("Read");

                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                    child: Card(
                      color:
                          isRead == "No" ? Colors.teal.shade100 : Colors.white,
                      child: Slidable(
                        endActionPane: ActionPane(
                          motion: const StretchMotion(),
                          children: [
                            SlidableAction(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                                label: "Delete",
                                onPressed: (contex) {
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection(widget.userCollection)
                                      .doc(uid)
                                      .collection(widget.notificationCollection)
                                      .doc(selectedUID)
                                      .delete();
                                })
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection(widget.userCollection)
                                .doc(uid)
                                .collection(widget.notificationCollection)
                                .doc(selectedUID)
                                .update({"Read": "Yes"});
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (_) => SimpleDialog(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
                                      title: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: screenHeight * 0.01,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            info.get("title"),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: screenHeight * 0.04,
                                          ),
                                          Text(info.get("Message")),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: screenHeight * 0.03,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            time,
                                            style:
                                                const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ));
                          },
                          title: Expanded(
                            child: TextScroll(
                              "${info.get("title")}.  ",
                              velocity: const Velocity(
                                  pixelsPerSecond: Offset(30, 0)),
                              style:
                                  const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          leading: Checkbox(
                            value: isCheckedList[index],
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                log('setStatCall with : $value and index at :$index');
                                isCheckedList[index] = value!;
                                if (value) {
                                  selectedList.add(index);
                                  log('setStatCall in not value with : $value and index at :$index');
                                  //check box of index=index is taped so adding it to  list
                                } else {
                                  selectedList.remove(index);
                                  log('setStatCall  in else value with : $value and index at :$index');
                                  //check box of index=index is taped to uncheck so removing it from the list
                                }
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }

            return Center(
              child: Text(widget.noNotificationYetString),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

see below if it helps

```
 class _GeneralNotificationState extends State<GeneralNotification> {
  List<int> selectedList = [];
  List<bool> isCheckedList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Utils().customAppBarTitleAndNav(context, 100,
          widget.notificationAppBarTitleString, widget.navigateToHomePage),
      body: Container(
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight,
        decoration: Utils().decoration(),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection(widget.userCollection)
              .doc(uid)
              .collection(widget.notificationCollection)
              .orderBy("Time", descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(widget.errorString);
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              isCheckedList = List.filled(snapshot.data!.docs.length, false);
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final info = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  var timestamp = info.get("Time") as Timestamp;

                  // var dateFormat = DateFormat("dd.M.yyy  hh:mm");
                  DateTime timeStamppp =
                      DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString());
                  String time =
                      DateFormat("EEE dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm").format(timeStamppp);
                  final selectedUID = info.get("uid");
                  final isRead = info.get("Read");

                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                    child: Card(
                      color:
                          isRead == "No" ? Colors.teal.shade100 : Colors.white,
                      child: Slidable(
                        endActionPane: ActionPane(
                          motion: const StretchMotion(),
                          children: [
                            SlidableAction(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                                label: "Delete",
                                onPressed: (contex) {
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection(widget.userCollection)
                                      .doc(uid)
                                      .collection(widget.notificationCollection)
                                      .doc(selectedUID)
                                      .delete();
                                })
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection(widget.userCollection)
                                .doc(uid)
                                .collection(widget.notificationCollection)
                                .doc(selectedUID)
                                .update({"Read": "Yes"});
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (_) => SimpleDialog(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
                                      title: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: screenHeight * 0.01,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            info.get("title"),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: screenHeight * 0.04,
                                          ),
                                          Text(info.get("Message")),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: screenHeight * 0.03,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            time,
                                            style:
                                                const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ));
                          },
                          title: Expanded(
                            child: TextScroll(
                              "${info.get("title")}.  ",
                              velocity: const Velocity(
                                  pixelsPerSecond: Offset(30, 0)),
                              style:
                                  const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          leading: Checkbox(
                            value: isCheckedList[index],
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                log('setStatCall with : $value and index at :$index');
                                isCheckedList[index] = value!;
                                if (value) {
                                  selectedList.add(index);
                                  log('setStatCall in not value with : $value and index at :$index');
                                  //check box of index=index is taped so adding it to  list
                                } else {
                                  selectedList.remove(index);
                                  log('setStatCall  in else value with : $value and index at :$index');
                                  //check box of index=index is taped to uncheck so removing it from the list
                                }
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }

            return Center(
              child: Text(widget.noNotificationYetString),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the check box is not selecting.

Comment: did you check that the part `if (value!) {
                  selectedList.add(index);
                    //check box of index=index is taped so adding it to  list
                } else {
                  selectedList.remove(index);
             //check box of index=index is taped to uncheck so removing it from the list
                }` is being called on click ?

Comment: I did as you wrote. AAMOF, I copied and pasted it

Comment: i added some log lines tell me what you see when you click on any check box

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not working

Comment: are you able to see logs? also you passed the correct path to `stream: db.collection...`  right ?

Comment: Yeah, with that I imported "dart:developer"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256944/discussion-between-rainy-sidewalks-and-ebenezer-ocansey).